# How to make the "one scroll" on a one page website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'll start by linking you [what](https://mega.nz/) I'm talking about.
I'd like to know how to make such a scroll like that, you just need to scroll once and boom you'll get to the next section.

Thus, how to make a one page website (yeah, maybe I'll add some more sections but wanted to know what are the properties to do that)
[This](http://www.dtelepathy.com/blog/inspiration/22-fresh-single-page-website-for-your-inspiration) is what I mean by one page websites.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [scroll a full page height up or down with jQuery/Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18953652/scroll-a-full-page-height-up-or-down-with-jquery-javascript)

Comment: on scroll you can either use animate and then scrollTop to that section or another way is use translateY on scroll but beware that scroll event fire at high rate so you need to throttle down event you can requestAnimation frame, don't animate on scroll instead just change Y value
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37502075/parallax-effect-make-elements-follow-scroll-with-delay/37502722#37502722

Answer (score 1):

Try [FullPage](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/); it supports both vertical and horizontal sections.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of libraries available. I would suggest [Fullpage](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) for this kind of CSS. It will provide you some extra features like horizontal scroll within Vertical scroll which will make you site attractive.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Yeah this one was what I was talking about, but I have a question: I tried to put a background-image, 1366x768 px with these attributes: `background-size:     cover;                     
     background-repeat:   no-repeat;
     background-position: center center;`

Comment: so what is the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use class for each section of your page and then by using of that classname and jquery you can do the same.For more information and demo you can check the link below.It may help you.

You can check the demo and solution below here the one page section scrolling is given in great way.

[Check this demo](http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/scrolling-nav/)