# Floating elements follow parallax scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, jquery-plugins, parallax

I'm looking for a jquery plugin/code to do something similar to this sites:

http://melanie-f.com/en/
http://www.adidas.co.uk/climazone

The elements float with some sort of easing following the scroll movement, so they create kind of a parallax effect.

Someone else posted something similar, but the demo link is down right now: [Parallax effect make elements follow scroll with delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37502075/parallax-effect-make-elements-follow-scroll-with-delay)

I've been searching really hard, but I can't seem to find anything apart from the post above.

I'm not really good at coding JS from scratch, so that's why I'm looking for a plugin.

Thanks a lot in advance for the help...

(And I'm really sorry if the subject of this question is duplicated.)

Comment: none of the links work in 2023 :)